# Code sql for export record

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [[SELECT count(*) FROM [Groups Leader]]/[SELECT count(*) FROM [ALL LSE STUDENTs]]]
FROM [ALL STUDENTs Random]
WHERE [Get it?] = No
UPDATE  [ALL STUDENTs Random]
SET [Get it?]= Yes;
```

I need to export a number of record from a query. This number is the entire division of the numbers of report of two table. In addition to this i need to be sure that the report that i export are not already changed in 'YES' in the 'Yes/no' Field. and for sure the report that i export need to be changed in YES in that Field.

i've tryed to do the sql code to simple as possible but i've been started with this programming code only a week ago.

Comment: I assume you are using TSQL, where do you want to export it? In terms of exporting data from SQL to an other program like C#,Delphi,Java, there are special tools inside each IDE. YOu have to be a little bit more specific in order for us to help you.

Comment: i would export those record to a specific table of the database access!

Comment: You should link rather than export, and that's if you're sold on using Access's forms and reports rather than looking at SSRS and an active scripting interface language like ASP or PHP. check this article for help. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx